# Code coverage metrics when using groovy AST transforms

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, annotations, code-coverage, abstract-syntax-tree

We use several AST transforms in our groovy code, such as `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode`. We use these so we don't have to maintain and test them. The problem is that code coverage metrics (using jacoco right now but open to change if it will help) don't know these are autogenerated methods and they cause a lot of code to appear uncovered even though it's not actually code we're writing.

Is there a way to include these from coverage metrics in any tools?

I guess you could argue that since we're putting the annotations we should still be testing the code being generated since a unit test shouldn't care how these methods are created, but just that they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with @Log and the conditionals that it inserts into the code. That gets reported (cobertura) as a lack of branch coverage.

But as you said: it just reports it correctly. The code is not covered.

If you don't need the code, you should not have generated it. If you need it and aim for full test coverage, you must test it or at least "exercise" it, i.e. somehow use it from your test cases even without asserts.

From a test methodology standpoint, not covering generated code is equally questionable as using exclusion patterns. From a pragmatic standpoint, you may just want to live with it.

Comment: I'll agree to just live with it. The `equals` method can be a lot more complicated to test (there are some automated tools to help though). If you have a few attributes, it would take a few tests such that every instruction is exercised since two objects could be not equal if any of the attributes are not equal. The whole purpose of the annotation is that I know it works, but from a purist point of view, you are correct that it is not actually being exercised.